# Extracting 2d patches from 3d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

scikit-learn's [`extract_patches_2d`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) can be used to reshape a 2D image into a collection of patches.  [`extract_patches`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L241) is the generalized form that uses NumPy's `as_strided`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image

ex = np.arange(3 * 3).reshape(3, 3)
image.extract_patches_2d(ex, patch_size=(2, 2))
[[[0 1]
  [3 4]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]]

 [[3 4]
  [6 7]]

 [[4 5]
  [7 8]]]
```

I have a three-dimensional array `a` and would like to extract 2d patches from each "innermost" 2d array, then find the (axis-agnostic) mean of each 2d patch.

```
a = np.arange(2 * 3 * 3).reshape(2, 3, 3)
```

In this case, I effectively want to first call `extract_patches_2d` on each (3, 3) inner array.

```
patches = np.array([image.extract_patches_2d(i, patch_size=(2, 2)) for i in a])
```

and then find the mean of each innermost 2d array (each patch):

```
means = patches.reshape(*patches.shape[:-2], -1).mean(axis=-1)
print(means)
[[  2.   3.   5.   6.]
 [ 11.  12.  14.  15.]]
```

How can I vectorize this and get rid of the for-loop above?  The important thing here is that the size of the first dimension of `means` is equal to the size of `a`'s first dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scikit-image as `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get those `patches` as a `view` into input array -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

size = 2 # patch size
patches = view_as_windows(a, (1,size,size))[...,0,:,:]
```

This gives us a `5D` array as `patches`, on which we can use `mean` reduction along the last two axes for a `3D` output -

```
out = patches.mean((-2,-1))
```

If the final output is needed as a `2D` one, reshape to merge last two axes -

```
out.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

This can also utilize `sklearn`'s [`extract_patches`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L241):

```
def inner_means(arr_3d, patch_size):
    """Axis-agnostic mean of each 2d patch.

    Maintains the first dimension of `arr_3d`.

    patch_size: tuple
        Same syntax as the parameter passed to extract_patches_2d
    """
    shape = (1,) + patch_size
    patches = image.extract_patches(arr_3d, shape)[..., 0, :, :].mean((-2, -1))
    return patches.reshape(*patches.shape[:-2], -1)


a = np.arange(2 * 3 * 3).reshape(2, 3, 3)
    print(inner_means(a, patch_size=(2, 2)))

[[  2.   3.   5.   6.]
 [ 11.  12.  14.  15.]]
```

---

Alternatively, to directly get to the blocky average values, we can use one of those convolution tools from Scipy. So with `fftconvolve` -

```
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

out = fftconvolve(a, np.ones((1,size,size)),mode='valid')/size**2
```

Or use `scipy.signal.convolve` or `scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter` there without the division.

Comment: Nice.  I think the equivalent staying in sklearn would be `image.extract_patches(a, (1, 2, 2))[...,0,:,:].mean((-2, -1))`.

Comment: I'm not sure what would possibly be faster than this approach, but it's having a lot of trouble on a (2093, 256, 202) array regardless of patch size.

Comment: sorry, nevermind--had a couple processes running simultaneously and that was slowing things up

Comment: @BradSolomon Also, do try out the conv based approach added at the end.

Comment: Thanks--the sklearn/skimage implementation is faster in my case by about 3x.  But that could be input-specific